# Limit Exec Commands for Linux Users

Tags: linux, centos, user-permissions, exec

**How can I limit the scope of executable commands a linux user can run?**

For example, I only want user to be able to run the `ls` command and nothing else. If tried, for example to run `cat`, linux would throw an error or return null.

I've looked into the `alias` command to set a predefined list of custom commands, but this doesn't limit the user from running other commands. I actually would love to set `alias` commands then limit the scope to just those.

I've also looked into [this documentation](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Security-Enhanced_Linux/#chap-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Confining_Users) on confining users, but still unsure about how to go about it.

Scope: I'm using a service account to run ssh commands within our PHP app. I want to limit the commands for that service account to prevent a situation where someone injects commands into the `ssh_exec();` - such as `ls` and inject `| some command`

I think I'll try this: https://github.com/ghantoos/lshell

Comment: Can you tell us more about why you think you need to do this?  There are several different approaches that may apply here, but you need to give us more context so we can advise you.  Or are you just looking for a getting started guide to selinux?

Comment: See above Scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also bind commands to specific ssh keys in the authorized keys file.

```
from="host.com",command="/bin/ls" ssh-dss <SSH PUBLIC KEY>
```

What this does is restrict access to the account using a certain ssh public to only run a specific command from a specific host. See

```
man sshd
```

for more options.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably engage this situation by writing a wrapper script.
There is a part solution available here for you to begin with, please read up and see if you can't make it from this link.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92049/restrict-standard-users-to-run-a-command-with-a-specific-argument

I know this specifies the use of UID, if you need this for several users, think in terms of using GID instead and putting all these kinds of users in that very same group.

Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit command executions of SSH users, you can use `ChrootDirectory` introduced in `OpenSSH 4.9p1`

- [Chroot users with OpenSSH: An easier way to confine users to their home directories - TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/chroot-users-with-openssh-an-easier-way-to-confine-users-to-their-home-directories/)

You will also find a statically-linked binary of `busybox` useful in setting up a chroot environment.  (The above article pays a lot of effort to set up a complete chroot environment.)

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58074/how-to-chroot-into-busybox-environment